# Shrink a line of verse

Tags: spacing, fontspec

I have some lines of Sanskrit verse (left indented via a `quoting` environment) which are slightly too long, similar to the following example:

[image: third line is too long.]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0pt,indentfirst=false]
Some verse XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX |\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX || 1 ||\\
Second verse XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX |\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX || 2 || \\
\end{quoting}
Some more text again.
\end{document}
```

Each half-verse is ended by a pipe-sign, and each full verse ended by the verse number enclosed in double pipe-signs. The second half of the first verse in the example is slightly too long, so that a line break occurs. I would now like to reduce inter word space and/or inter letter space just for this line in order to avoid the line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fontspec` via its `\addfontfeatures` command actually allows one to conveniently adjust the settings for inter-word and inter-letter spaces for fonts loaded by it:

[image: updated output]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newcommand\myshrink{\addfontfeature{WordSpace=0.95,LetterSpace=-0.5}}
\newcommand\myshrinkmore{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.9,LetterSpace=-1}}
\newcommand\myshrinkevenmore{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.85,LetterSpace=-1.5}}
\newcommand\myshrinkharder{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.5,LetterSpace=-5}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0pt,indentfirst=false]
Some verse XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX |\\
%XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX || 1 ||\\
%{\myshrink XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\
%{\myshrinkmore XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\
%{\myshrinkevenmore XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\
{\myshrinkharder XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\
Second verse XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX |\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX || 2 ||
\end{quoting}
Some more text again.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a local change, you could set the `leftmargin` to something smaller than the default `\leftmargin`.

The package `microtype` helps, as so often. And you should put a tilde between parts you do not want to get separated.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    Some text
    \begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0pt,indentfirst=false, leftmargin=.9\leftmargin] % your example just needs microtype but just to show...
        Some verse XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX |\\
        XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX ||~1~||\\
        Second verse XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX |\\
        XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX ||~2~|| \\
    \end{quoting}
    Some more text again.
\end{document}
```

If you just need a little tweak here, I would recommend to put this globally in your preamble as `\quotingsetup{leftmargin=.9\leftmargin}` as this will change all your quotes. Better for consistency.

[image]

In any case, I would not do a real shrinking. That looks ugly IMO. It would be preferable to enter a line break at some good point and to flush the second line to the right.

Comment: `microtype` doesn't do anything if I compile with `xelatex`, `luatex` is needed for that, is it?

Comment: no, pdflatex will do fine, also.

Comment: @muk.li You should put such information in your post as XeLaTeX is not standard. I just guessed something due to your `fontspec` loading. I fear that XeLaTeX does not work (completely) with `microtype`

Answer (score 2):

If it is only from time to time and manual work is allowed, you can simply write

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{quoting}[rightmargin=0pt,indentfirst=false]
Some verse XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX |\\
\scalebox{0.95}[1]{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\ % the precise value by an experiment
Second verse XXXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX |\\
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX || 2 || \\
\end{quoting}
Some more text again.
\end{document}
```

If the factor of x-transformation is close to 1 (0.95 in this example) the result should be acceptable.