# Underfull \hboxes when reducing inter word and inter letter spaces

Tags: spacing, fontspec, warnings

Related to [this question about shrinking a line of verse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264348/shrink-a-line-of-verse) I still don't understand why I'm getting an `Underfull \hbox` warning for the following example. As far as I understand this warning normally means that latex has to stretch inter word space because of a long word not fitting at the end of the line any more and needing to be printed at the beginning of the next line, its normal solution being to hyphenate that long word. But here we are dealing with one line only. Where exactly is that `Underfull \hbox` here?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
{\addfontfeatures{WordSpace=0.5,LetterSpace=-5} XXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXX} || 1 ||\\
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: Word spacing or letter spacing are not involved. You have a lonely ``\\`` followed by `\end{document}` (also a blank line would produce the same). ***Never*** use ``\\`` just to end a paragraph: blank lines are used for that.

Comment: the underful box is a completely empty line that you have forced at the end of the paragraph by forcing a linebreak at the end. It may look a bit like vertical space but it is not it is a blank (and very underfull) line so it does not strecth vertically and is not discarded at a page break.